# Uncaught TypeError: a is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have this:

```
let dateDataStartDate = moment().startOf('week')._d
let dateDataEndDate = moment().endOf('week')._d
if (datesData.start != undefined) {
  dateDataStartDate = datesData.start
  dateDataEndDate = datesData.end
}

axios.get('/api/classes/' + props.myVal, {
      params: {
          dateDataStartDate: dateDataStartDate,
          dateDataEndDate: dateDataEndDate,
          admin: true
      }
  })
```

when I run this code, I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: a is undefined
```

and this error corresponds to this line from my console output:

```
let dateDataEndDate = moment().endOf('week')._d
```

Does anyone have any idea what the problem could be?

**UPDATE**

Problem was solved by fixing `if (datesData.start != undefined) {`

what was happening was that `datesData` is undefined, which means the object element `.start` doesn't exist. So it seems that I am trying to access a non-existent object element, and it was failing. So to fix it, I did:

```
if (datesData != undefined) {
```

weird, but it works

Comment: I don't see how that code could cause that error; it works fine for me.

Comment: strange... I went on safari and tried it, and it gave me a more descriptive error: ```TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'a.start')```

Comment: I tried in node js it works for me. Just check which version of  moment.js you are using.

Comment: @MithiridiPrasanth hmm. moment v is 2.29.3

Answer (score 0):

#### You can tell that the error is not within your code snippet

By the time the error occurs, in your 2nd line, there is no variable `a`.

```
let dateDataStartDate = moment().startOf('week')._d
let dateDataEndDate = moment().endOf('week')._d
if (datesData.start != undefined) {
  dateDataStartDate = datesData.start
  dateDataEndDate = datesData.end
}

axios.get('/api/classes/' + props.myVal, {
      params: {
          dateDataStartDate: dateDataStartDate,
          dateDataEndDate: dateDataEndDate,
          admin: true
      }
  })
```

If the error really is coming from that line, then it can't be from failure to define `moment()`, since it got past the first line.

Therefore there must be something wrong with the `moment` software, and probably in its `endOf()` module.

As @Mithiridi Prasanth says, do check that you are using an up to date version of NodeJs.

#### Debugging

##### Remove all the lines except the line causing the error

Are you still getting the error, and in the same line?

That line is not using any variables previously declared, and the later lines can't be the cause of the earlier error, if you are right about the site of the error.

##### Try a less deep access into moment()

```
let test1 = moment()
let test2 = moment().endOf
let test3 = moment().endOf('week')
let test4 = moment().endOf('week')._d
```

And `console.log` the results. That way you can see at what stage it is going wrong.